# Craft 3 - Matrix Block for currentUser

Tags: craft3, matrix, loop, current-user

I have a Matrix field named -> `certificado`

with block -> `certificados`

and fields -> `nomeDoCurso`, `curso`, `certificado`

My Matrix block has no entries but is associated with a user.

[image]

[image]

How can I fetch the content of the Matrix block for a particular user in the frontend?

I'm trying with:

```
{% for item in currentUser.certificado %}
    {{ dump(item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this is wrong.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, many tries later, I found a way to do it.

```
{% for block in currentUser.certificado %}
<div>
    <h3>{{ block.nomeDoCertificado }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ block.curso[0] }}</h3>
    <a href="{{ block.certificado[0].url }}" target="_blank">{{ block.nomeDoCertificado }}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It is as simple as that :)